# Could not link another auth method - firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am signing in user using mobile number and then i want him to enter email and password later. (after logging in)

I am trying to link **email,password Auth** method to current **PhoneAuth** method.

But it's giving me an error:

> Cannot read property 'link' of undefined

Here is code:

```
import { firebaseAuth,fire,  messaging } from '../../config/constants';

var credential = fire.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
fire.auth.currentUser.link(credential).then(function(user) {
  console.log("Account linking success", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Account linking error", error);
});
```

And in **config/constants**

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
require("firebase/firestore");
const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxKXI",
    authDomain: "payxxxxxxxxxxxxja1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://payxxxxxxxxxxja1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "payxxxxxxxxxxxxja1",
    storageBucket: "payxxxxxxxxxxxja1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "281xxxxx5xxxxx6"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const fire = firebase
export const ref = firebase.database().ref()
export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth
export const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I think something is wrong with fire.auth or fire.auth()

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` has been removed in favor of `linkWithCredential` starting with Firebase JS version 4.0.0: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.0.0

Also make sure the current user is ready:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange(user => {
  if (user) {
    // currentUser is not null.
  } else {
    // currentUser is null.
  }
});
```